# errors when backuping ubuntu11.04 with tar

Tags: backup, ubuntu-11.04

I've been trying to backup my ubuntu11.04 with the following tar command

```
sudo tar -cvpzf /media/TOSHIBA\ EXT/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/dev --exclude=/home/manuzhang/Music --exclude=/home/manuzhang/Videos --exclude=/home/manuzhang/Pictures --exclude=/home/.aMule /
```

every time there is such a failure message

```
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors <br/>
```

the procedure exited when packaging the directory /sbin several times. Finally I exclude it, but it exited in /root 
So what caused the problem?
Anyone has similar experiences? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error `"Exiting with failure status due to previous errors" means *exactly* that. There was an earlier problem which, while not fatal to the running of the program, is reason enough to exit with a failure code.

Given that you're backing up from the root level, this is almost certainly because a file is not able to be backed up for some reason.

Leave off the verbose flag `-v` and you should hopefully be able to see the problem better.